# proper formula for this geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to properly write the expression for this geometric series that converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ for all x > 1. It looks like this:

$x = 2, f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$

$x = 3, f(x) = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$

$x = 4, f(x) = \frac{1}{24} + \frac{2}{24} + \frac{3}{24} + \frac{6}{24} = \frac{1}{2}$

etc.

What is the general equation for this? I can see that the number of actual terms is $1$ term for $x=2$, $2$ terms for $x=3$, $4$ terms for $x=4$, so I figured that the number of terms was $2^{x-2}$. To sum the fractions, the denominator of each term can be $x!$ and the numerator follows the sequence $\{1,2,3,6...\}$ which I can't identify, which is where I'm stuck.

So something like this is... or am I on the wrong track entirely?

$\displaystyle\sum^{2^{x-2}}_{k=1} = \frac{1,2,3,6...}{x!} = \frac{1}{2}$

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: With the $x!$ in the denominator, you have a clear specification of the remaining value to be in the numerators of the new terms when moving from $x\to x+1$.  For $x=5$, you already have $12$ out of $120$, leaving $48$ to account for in the remaining terms... Also, unless there is something specific saying that the series is geometric, this is not such a series.

Comment: @abiessu. Amuzing result.

Answer (score 1):

From a "simple solution that meets the requirements" approach, I would recommend using numerators $x-1$ multiplied by each of the numerators from the sum for $f(x-1)$.  So for $x=5$ these additional numerators would be $4,8,12,24$ for the sum as $\frac{1+2+3+6+4+8+12+24}{120}$.  Breaking down individual terms could be somewhat tedious in terms of finding a non-recursive term definition.  From a value perspective, the recursive presentation might look like

$$f(x)=\frac{f(x-1)}x+\frac{(x-1)f(x-1)}x$$

which is obviously of the form $f(x)=f(x-1)$.